# Which abilities can a gold dragon in change shape form use?

Tags: dnd-5e, polymorph, dragons

Can an Adult Gold Dragon in Change Shape form use any of the following abilities?

- Multiattack.
- Bite. Melee Weapon Attack
- Claw. Melee Weapon Attack
- Tail. Melee Weapon Attack
- Frightful Presence.
- Fire Breath.
- Weakening Breath.
- Change Shape.

Comment: Hey, you've asked some questions lately about shape change, polymorph, and other similar spell/abilities. Just wondering if you're simply curious about these things or if there's some big question/problem you've been trying to answer with them, thanks!

Comment: Only curious ;)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the clarification then. Stay curious

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Only Change Shape

The adult gold dragon's Change Shape feature includes (DMG 114):

> In a new form, the dragon retains its alignment, hit points, Hit Dice, ability to speak, proficiencies, Legendary Resistance, lair actions, and Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores, as well as this action. Its statistics and capabilities are otherwise replaced by those of the new form, except any class features or legendary actions of that form.

Notably, its attack options are not on that list, but it does retain Shape Change, so that it can change back to dragon form.